# JS/CSS: How to change z-index value after scrolling down past 1200 pixels (in height)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed navigation bar with a few divs in it and I want my logo div to appear after the user scrolls down 1200 pixels in height on my website. I want to do this by increasing the css z-index value of my logo div as soon as it has reached that point.

I was thinking maybe I have to use css media queries PHP or Jquery? I don't have much experience with those at the moment though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using jQuery. Solution would look something like:

```
// Catch scroll event
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  // If user didn't scroll 1200px set default z-index
  if ($(this).scrollTop()<1200) { 
      $("#logo" ).css( "z-index", 0);
  } else {
      // If user scrolled 1200px change logo's z-index to 9999  
      $("#logo" ).css( "z-index", 9999);
  }
});
```

Also I believe using `z-index` for controlling the visibility of the logo is not a good idea. I would suggest hiding the logo and then showing it on scroll. For hiding you could use `style="display: none;"` attribute. Example: `<img src="..." style="display: none;"`. Also you could use `$("#logo" ).hide();` for that. For showing the logo use `.show()`. In case of the code above change `$("#logo" ).css( "z-index", 9999);` to `$("#logo" ).show();`

Comment: Sweet, thanks for answering :) That did the trick! It now appears when I scroll down past 1200px, but when I scroll back up into the 0 to 1200 px area it keeps showing. I would like the logo to be always hidden within that area. Any simple way I can alter the code to make that happen? :) Also what does the "return;" exactly do in your code?

Comment: @VeronePotez Always welcome! I've edited my answer. Please feel free to mark it as accepted:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 1200) {

        // user scrolled 1200 pixels or more

        $('.target').css('z-index', '10');
    }
});
```